# How to display please wait image while response is being returned from server

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using an Windows based application where I get a response from another server.

It's taking too much time so I want to display image of please wait to the user until it's done.

How can I do this?

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    WebRequest request = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    Stream stream = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;
    string url = txtURL.Text.ToString();

    if (url != "")
    {
        try
        {
            // Display Please Wait Image
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            string NavigateURL = "http://" + url + Properties.Settings.Default.portAppName;
            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(NavigateURL + "connectionParam/PostCon");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // My stuff
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You ca use Backgroundworker for it

Comment: can you please provide any idea

Answer (score 0):

```
                BackgroundWorker bw;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "Yes";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += BwOnDoWork;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Display Please Wait Image
        label1.Text = "No";

    }
    private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (!worker.CancellationPending)
        {

            if (label1.Text == "No")
            {

                WebRequest request = null;
                HttpWebResponse response = null;
                Stream stream = null;
                StreamReader reader = null;
                string url = txtURL.Text.ToString();
                if (url != "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Application.Run(new Form1());

                        string NavigateURL = "http://" + url + Properties.Settings.Default.portAppName;
                        request = HttpWebRequest.Create(NavigateURL + "connectionParam/PostCon");
                        request.Method = "POST";
                        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            // My stuff

                            worker.CancelAsync();
                            bw.CancelAsync();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the form contains your waiting image is `Form1`. Simply show and dispose the form can do the job:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    WebRequest request = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    Stream stream = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;
    string url = txtURL.Text.ToString();

    var form = new Form1();

    if (url != "")
    {
        try
        {
            // Display Please Wait Image
            form.Show();

            string NavigateURL = "http://" + url + Properties.Settings.Default.portAppName;
            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(NavigateURL + "connectionParam/PostCon");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // My stuff
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { }
        finally { form.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing same but the image on please wait on form1 not getting display until response is not receive